# Form popups twice and deletes files when I cancel

Tags: c#

Maybe i got a better idea. This was the original code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool pause = false;
    private bool cut1 = false;
    private bool copy1 = false;
    Form2 popup = new Form2();

  
    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // The lines with performed actions of a file
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
    
    //1st directory
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;         // Text of textBox2 = Path of fileSystemWatcher2
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
        }
    }
    //2nd directory
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher2.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox2.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;         // Text of textBox2 = Path of fileSystemWatcher2
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
        }
    }
    //log
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult resDialog = dlgSaveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlgSaveFile.FileName);
            StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText();
            foreach (string sItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sItem);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    //pause watching
    private void pause_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            pause = true;
            pause_button.Text = "Unpause";
        }
        else
        {
            pause = false;
            pause_button.Text = "Pause Watching";
        }
    }
    //clear listbox
    private void clear_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
    }

    private void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //copy a file
        if (copy1)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
            var source = FileBrowseBox.Text;
            var target = Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(source)));

            if (File.Exists(target))
            {

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.Delete(target);
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
        }
        //cut a file
        if (cut1)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
            var source = FileBrowseBox.Text;
            var target = Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(source)));

            if (File.Exists(target))
            {

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.Delete(target);
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Move(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                File.Move(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
        }
    }
    private void Browse_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileBrowseBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void Browse_destination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DestinationBox.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void CopyButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copy1 = true;
    }

    private void Cut_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cut1 = true;
    }
}
}
```

[image: My Application]

I want the Filewatcher to watch the path of the FileBrowseBox, but with the FileBrowseBox you have to choose a file. How do i watch the path the file is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that both copy1 and cut1 are true?
In your code you set the variables to true, regardless the state of the checkboxes.

Try to change the CheckedChanged-methods to

```
private void CopyButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkCopy.Checked)
    {
        copy1 = true;
        cut1 = false;
        // ToDo: Uncheck checkbox cut1
    }
    else
    {
        copy1 = false;
    {
}

private void Cut_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkCut.Checked)
    {
        cut1 = true;
        copy1 = false;
        // ToDo: Uncheck checkbox copy1
    }
    else
    {
        cut1 = false;
    {
}
```

Maybe it's more interesting to use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes?
When in the same group there can be only one checked while in your case both checkboxes can be checked.
Which make no sense since you can only copy or cut, not both at the same time.